# rspec converting repeat block into method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this context in my spec file.

```
  context 'get :index' do 
            it 'should be loaded successfully if current user is not customer' do
              sign_in @creative
              get :index
              response.should be_success 
            end
            it 'should redirect to root page if current user is customer' do 
              sign_in @customer
              get :index
              response.should redirect_to root_path
            end
          end

context 'post :create' do 
            it 'should be loaded successfully if current user is not customer' do
              sign_in @creative
              post :create
              response.should be_success 
            end
            it 'should redirect to root page if current user is customer' do 
              sign_in @customer
              post :create
              response.should redirect_to root_path
            end
          end
```

I repeat the same code in two different context.I convert it like this method but it doesn't work.

```
def check_user_sign_in(request_type, action)
      context '#{request_type} :#{action}' do 
        it 'should be loaded successfully if current user is not customer' do
          sign_in @creative
          request_type action
          response.should be_success 
        end
        it 'should redirect to root page if current user is customer' do 
          sign_in @customer
          request_type action
          response.should redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

Here the problem is I didn't use parameter as a method name.

Do you know how can I use it with dry way?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
context '#{request_type} :#{action}' do
```

will not work because string interpolation is not evaluated inside single quotes.

You must use **double quotes**:

```
a = 'alpha' #=> "alpha"
b = 'beta'  #=> "beta"

'#{a} #{b}' #=> "\#{a} \#{b}"

"#{a} #{b}" #=> "alpha beta"
```

Comment: Thanks.It's correct for context but what about using parameter as a method like request_type action.